# Openpyxl Reading Non-empty Cells as None

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have an .xlsx file which I edit in another Python script which inputs formulas into blocks of cells. When I view the sheet with Excel, I have no problem seeing the values which result from the formulas. When I try to access it again, `data_only=True` or not, I get the wrong results when I try to read the values.

With this code (`data_only=False`):

```
wb = load_workbook(filename='Week of August 26, 2019.xlsx')
ws = wb['Weekly Stats']

for x in range(2,15):
    for y in range(38,41):
        print(ws.cell(row=y,column=x).value)
```

I end up with a long list of formulas:

```
...
=SUM(I3,I10,I17,I24,I31)
=SUM(I4,I11,I18,I25,I32)
=SUM(I5,I12,I19,I26,I33)
=SUM(I6,I13,I20,I27,I34)
...
```

If I run it with `data_only=True`, then I get a long list like:

```
None
None
None
...
```

Which is not what the Excel shows me when I open up the file itself. I don't have this issue when I manually input the formulas into excel, but if I put in the formulas using openpyxl, openpyxl has a hard time reading those values.

I've tried messing around with different combinations of `data_only=True` for both when I edit the Excel sheet and when I read it. It all leads to the same results. [Here is what the Excel sheet looks like (formula for one of the cells is in the top section).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoKW3.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** I noticed another similar question with a similar issue, but in my case, I'm only editing an existing file, not creating a new one that I'm trying to read from (a suggested answer from the other question.)

Even if I am reading from an openpyxl-created workbook, is there any way "refresh" or evaluate my formulas so that I can get the data from them? The file is saved before it's accessed again, so I would think there shouldn't be an issue?

Comment: openpyxl just does not support formulas (or they upgraded it without me noticing).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre so then how would I go about editing in formulas through openpyxl such that I can access the data in a later python script?

Comment: After looking into more similar questions, I found that the formulas have to be evaluated via Excel before openpyxl can read the value that's generated. When I ran my scripts and then opened and saved the file, I was able to read the values.
Still trying to figure out how to do that in an automated fashion. I could run a batch file that would could open the files, but I don't know about saving them, not to mention that seems extremely inefficient and unnecessary, but I'm blanking on other options...